# PhP mysql - how to show records from database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my first post in this community. I am a new to PHP and MySQL. Here is the code that I am trying to run.

I'm using MAMP. I have tested that I am able to establish connection to the "pet" database. Checked my user name and password, that's correct too. I have data in the database with "horse" in the field "petType".

There is got to be something wrong in the code below. I have scratched my head and looked in books and online, but couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong? With the code below, my webpage comes blank.

I'm trying to display records from the database as the first part and worry about formatting later.

---

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$username = ' ';
$password = ' ';
$database = 'pet';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

$query= "SELECT * FROM pet WHERE petType = 'horse'";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
{   
$petDescription = $query [$petDescription];
$petName = $query [$petName];
$petType = $query [$petType];

echo "$petType <br> <br> $petName <br> $petDescription";

}

?>
```

Comment: You merely have a string in `$query`. At no point are you ***executing*** that query against your database.

Comment: You're not querying. Here, read up on the subject http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Plus, what the *ahem* is `$petDescription = $query [$petDescription];
$petName = $query [$petName];
$petType = $query [$petType];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's the rundown.

- You're not querying. This means that you need to use the [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function, which requires a successful [**DB connection**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) established and passed as the first parameter.
- Then you're assigning `$row` in the `while` loop to fetch the array, yet you're using `$query` as its replacement for the intended rows to be echo'd. It should be `$row` and not `$query`.

(Edit) You also have a colon in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):` <= delete it.

Now, it's hard to know for certain as to what your actual column names are in your table, so I'll just replace them with generic `column_x`, `column_y` and  `column_z` for now.

You can replace those with the ones that are in your table. More on this a bit further below.

Replace your current block of code with the following:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pet WHERE petType = 'horse'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {   
        $petType = $row['column_x'];
        $petName = $row['column_y'];
        $petDescription = $row['column_z'];

        echo "$petType <br> <br> $petName <br> $petDescription";

    }
```

If what your other columns are indeed called `petType`, `petName` and `petDescription`, then you can replace the above with:

```
$petType = $row['petType'];
$petName = $row['petName'];
$petDescription = $row['petDescription'];
```

The way it works is this, and I will show you in a graphical way:

```
$petType = $row['petType'];
    ^        ^      ^
    |        |      | column name in table
    |        |
    |        | variable in loop
    |
    | variable to echo
```

However, there is something that seems a bit unclear and that both your DB and table hold the same name of `pet`.

Make sure that is indeed the case.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

- Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.
- *Otherwise*, you will be open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Comment: Hey, you guys are awesome. I tried the suggestions that you gave me yet, the code isn't working. My database and table are both "pet" and fields are as you see below.New code-
$host = 'localhost';
$username = ' ';
$password = ' ';
$database = 'pet';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pet WHERE petType = 'horse'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): {   
 $petType = $row['$petType'];
 $petName = $row['$petName'];
 $petDescription = $row['petDescription']; echo "$petType <br> <br> $petName <br> $petDescription";
}
<?

Comment: @divinelotus You're welcome. You will need to define "isn't working" though. Go over my entire answer again and very carefully.

Comment: @divinelotus the last part of your code reads as `<br> $petName <br> $petDescription"; } <?` that should read as `<br> $petName <br> $petDescription"; } ?>` - notice the `<?` that should be `?>`

Comment: @divinelotus Plus, I spotted another thing, a colon in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):` which should not be there and I have deleted it in my answer. An oversight on my part. It should just be `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` - TBH, my screen is a bit dirty and I didn't see it originally because of it lol

Comment: Awesome, Fred -ii-, it worked!!!! Thanks a million. I was struggling for the past three days to make this work and it worked because of you!!! You are a rock-star..